# From a systemic functional approach, what would a transitivity analysis of 'be that as it may' show?

Tags: systemic-functional

I found this beautifully organized text for my students to analyze in terms of thematic progression. I'll also ask them to provide a transitivity analysis of some of its clauses, but there's that expression that caught me off guard.

I suppose it's a relational process 'be' followed by the carrier 'that' (which is already odd).

Then we get to 'as it may'. Would you say it's a conjunctive adjunct followed by a carrier and an elliptical attributive process (may be)?

Is there any other way to interpret it?

Answer (score -1):

"be that as it may" starts with a subjunctive "
be that", which can be paraphrased as "**if** that is". 
The next phrase is a fragment, paraphrased as "as it may **be**" ('as' is a conjunction here, meaning 'like').  The copulas in each phrase are empty, so the 'be' is existential (the complement is its existence, or truth; therefore a full paraphrase would be "if that is true, as it may be true".  The author is trying to explain something without admitting that what was stated is true.

Comment: I'd disagree slightly with this analysis. The copulas are not empty, but rather "as it may [be]" is the complement of the first "be"; and the phrase isn't a conditional but a concessive paraphrasable with "let". A full paraphrase would be "Let that be as it may be".

Comment: @TKR - Can the concession be 'letting'? I have a problem seeing an imperative as an adverbial.  I don't mind calling it a complement, but I still see it deeply as adverbial, as it would be if there was a real complement.cf. "Be that a cougar or a puma, as it may well be [one], I wouldn't try to pet it."

Comment: @aml I'm afraid I don't understand your comment (what imperative? *Be* here is subjunctive), but compare examples like *Be the answer what it may*, which can't by analyzed in the way you're proposing.

Comment: @TKR - your paraphrase "Let that be ..." is clearly imperative.  A reduced subjunctive (no conjunction) always means 'if'.  Why can't I paraphrase "Be the answer what it may" as "If the answer is what it may be"?

Comment: Well, paraphrasing as "If the answer is what it may be" takes you one step closer to my analysis since you're now taking "what it may be" as the complement of the copula, same as I'm arguing for "as it may". It's not true that subjunctives without a conjunction always mean "if", cf. *God save the Queen*. But the broader point is that *Be the answer what it may* is not used to mean "If the answer is what it may be, (then...)", but "Let the answer be whatever it may be, (nevertheless...)"; likewise for *Be that as it may*. Eliding *true* is also a problem, as is the lack of a comma after *that*.

Comment: I'm fine with 'complement', and the lack of comma does make it less 'adjunct'.  What is the reduced conjunction in "God save the Queen"?  It seems more like an aside -- an idiomatic redirected imperative.  I think we're both answering that "be that" has inversion because it is subjunctive, but then we're arguing about what was elided.  Perhaps the most *meaningful* paraphrase today is just "whatever it may be".

Comment: I wouldn't think in terms of elision or "reduction" at all; *God save the Queen* is simply a subjunctive with a jussive or optative sense. Anyway it looks like we now agree on the basic structure but differ as to whether *Be that as it may* is conditional or concessive in sense. That's an empirical question; I can say that as a native speaker the conditional meaning is impossible for me (what would "If that is as it may be" actually mean?), and that I'm quite sure that looking at its usage in real contexts would show that the concessive meaning is what's intended.

Comment: Then (stickling over punctuation, as you did), wouldn't 'letting' be better than 'let' in your paraphrase?

Comment: If you prefer, sure. I think either is OK since the meaning is the same.

Comment: Let me see, you are right.

Comment: "God save the queen" is a terrible choice of an example, because it's a prescriptive idiom not taken from natural language. May that as it be (I used to mix it up like that, so "may" is the headword which really makes it subjunctive, isn't it?), there's no syntactic distinction between imperative and subjunctive in those examples. The distinction is paradigmatic, not syntagmatic; if that is making any sense (still learning). Please compare my attempt at an answer.

Comment: @vectory - I still think subordinate uses of "be it" ..."were they" are hiding an **'if'**.  Your mixup is cute, but it jumbles nested clauses.  I still think "let it be" is imperative, even if it can be a jussive dependent.  Will you post an answer?  I wish TKR would.

Comment: Hello, everyone! After considering your paraphrases I came up with another interpretation based on what vectory proposed. Though odd, "may that as it be" made me realize that it is indeed a relational process. I still assume it is attributive... the attribute being taken from the preceding clause.

Comment: @FacundoMorales - there's a reason no one but vectory says it that way.  If it devolves into an idiom then it may have a tortured paraphrase (adding more than can safely be assumed).